# Newsletter preview doesn't work over HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl, newsletter

When viewing the [Newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) page over an `https` connection I am unable preview any newsletter. The dialog that is displayed is blank.

[image: newsletter preview blank dialog]

The error I get in the console is:

> Mixed Content: The page at
> 'https://stackexchange.com/newsletters' was loaded over HTTPS, but
> requested an insecure resource
> 'https://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=stackoverflow.com&suppressPromotion=true'.
>
> This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

When attempting to preview the Newsletters under `http` everything works fine and the dialog is displayed as expected.

[image: newsletter preview]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preview was using the link for the newsletter, which was always set to http.

I have made the link use the same protocol as the one loading the page, which fixes the issue.